# Run a bash script one and stop

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, cron, slack

I have this simple script that checks if mysql on remote servers (db-test-1 and db-test-2) is in SST mode and sends a message to a slack channel. The script is running on a third server dedicated for running cron jobs. Here is the code below:

```
#!/bin/bash

time=$(date);
array=( db-test-1 db-test-2 )
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
        S=$(ssh $i ps -ef |grep mysql | grep wsrep_sst_xtrabackup-v2);
        if [[ "$S" != "" ]]; then
                curl -X POST --data-urlencode "payload={\"channel\": \"#db-share-test\", \"username\": \"wsrep_local_state_comment\", \"text\": \"*$i*: ${time}\n>State transfer in progress, setting sleep higher mysqld\", \"icon_emoji\": \":scorpion:\"}" https://hooks.slack.com/services/G824ZJS9N/B6QS5JEKP/ZjV1hmM1k4dZGsf9HDC1o1jd
                exit 0
        else
                curl -X POST --data-urlencode "payload={\"channel\": \"#db-share-test\", \"username\": \"wsrep_local_state_comment\", \"text\": \"*$i*: ${time}\n>State transfer is complete. Server is Synced now.\", \"icon_emoji\": \":scorpion:\"}" https://hooks.slack.com/services/G824ZJS9N/B6QS5JEKP/ZjV1hmM1k4dZGsf9HDC1o1jd
                exit 2

        fi
done
```

The two servers, db-test1 and db-test-2 are part of a PXC cluster. So when i start db-test-1 in  SST to join the cluster, i get the following in my slack channel as expected:

```
*db-test-1*: Sun Aug 27 15:12:44 CST 2017
>State transfer in progress, setting sleep higher mysqld

[3:12] 
*db-test-1*: Sun Aug 27 15:12:49 CST 2017
State transfer in progress, setting sleep higher mysqld

[3:12] 
*db-test-1*: Sun Aug 27 15:12:51 CST 2017
State transfer in progress, setting sleep higher mysqld

[3:12] 
*db-test-1*: Sun Aug 27 15:12:54 CST 2017
State transfer in progress, setting sleep higher mysqld
```

So the results are being displayed approximately every 3 seconds. However, the cron job executing this script is scheduled to run every minute, hence not sure why it is sending results every 3 seconds or so as shown above.

How can i ensure that the results are displayed every 1 minute to avoid my channel being thrown the same message every 3 seconds? Also, how can i make sure that when the SST is finished, a single message to slack to indicate that the state transfer is finished instead of sending this message none-stop every time the two db servers are not in SST mode?

Comment: I think we are missing some info. Your current script will always exit after the `if [[ "$S" != "" ]];`, so the for-loop will not get further than the first `i`. Does it work when you call it by the commandline, can you post your crontab entry and do you have another loop somewhere that you did not post?

Comment: I don't think you want `--data-urlencode` for JSON data.

Comment: The code is simple and that is the complete code with all for loops included.

Comment: I hope these are fake URLs for those hooks.

Comment: @TheGeorgia: First of all, your script doesn't make sense. You set up a loop over an array with two elements (BTW using an *unnecessary* array, because the content is static anyway), but you exit the script after the first element has been processed. Second, you ask about an oddity in cron starting the processes too frequently, but you don't post your crontab.

Comment: * * * * * /path/to/my/script.  This is my crontab

Answer (score 1):

Besides checking that the `cron` is properly set, probably something like:

```
@every_minute /path/to/script
```

or

```
*/1 * * * * /path/to/script
```

It could be also good to ensure that only one occurrence of the program is running, try adding this to your script used within the cron job

```
*/1 * * * * pgrep script > /dev/null || /path/to/script
```

or by using something like:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

if ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep your_script_name ; then
    exit 0
fi
# your code goes below
# ...
```